# dotnet EF Core migrations add only works when my Rider IDE is closed

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, entity-framework-core, rider

I started using Jetbrains' Rider IDE to develop ***.NET Core applications***. I was going through some ***Entity Framework*** problems regarding the Build failing whenever I do some migrations because the "*Process cannot access the file "filename" because it is being used by another process*" (As shown by the --verbose).

I came to a deduction that the "other process" was my Rider IDE. I closed the IDE, executed "**dotnet ef migrations add**" then finally got "Build Succesful". Why is it that when I do "migrations add" with Visual Studio's Nuget Package Console, it seems to be able to access the files and create the migration folder and the files inside it on the go?

Is there any way I can make it so that the Rider IDE does not interfere with the process?

Comment: I can run `dotnet ef migrations add ..` with same project being opened in Rider. Are you sure that you weren't in the middle of debugging or building?

Comment: Yeah the build fails as long as rider is open

Answer (score 0):

I am using Rider as my primary IDE when developing in general, including when using or developing the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` EF Core provider.

I have to admit though, that I never tried using Visual Studio's package manager console in parallel to Rider. What I usually do, is either to open a PowerShell/Windows Terminal window or use the Rider Terminal functionality (configured to use PowerShell) in parallel and then run a `dotnet ef migrations add Foo --verbose` command. Works every time for me without any problem.

Try it again on a simple console project with a single table and no extension (except for EF Core and the provider you are using) or other projects, and see if it works.

Maybe it's just time to click on `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.